# How to convert mysqli_query result to int?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Currently I'm developing a mobile library app, which will need to check out books. I would like to be able to check how many books are checked out compared to the total available. I am struggling to covert the `mysqli_query`  result into an integer to compare to the amount of total books available. I apologize if this is an easy answer (I'm very new), as I did quite a bit of digging and could't find an answer that I could adapt to fit my scenario.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$userID = "2";
$book_id = "1";

$mysql_qry = "select COUNT(*) from books_checked_out where bookID=$book_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

//Somewhere here convert the $result into $quantity, which would be an int

if($quantity >= 2) {
    echo "more books checked out than in stock";
}
else if($quantity < 2) {
    echo "less books checked out than in stock";
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `compared to the total available`-> from where you are going to get `total available`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$userID = "2";
$book_id = "1";

$mysql_qry = "select COUNT(*) as quantity from books_checked_out where bookID=$book_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, 'MYSQLI_ASSOC'); // Use something like this to get the result
$quantity = $row['quantity'];

if($quantity >= 2) {
    echo "more books checked out than in stock";
}
else if($quantity < 2) {
    echo "less books checked out than in stock";
}
?>
```

Comment: However it's not explained why in mysql queries under PHP, all numbers are converted to string. In your example the variable $quantity will be a string where it should be an integer. To obtain the integer one must use $quantity = intval($row['quantity']); and it's not clear why.

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
$result = $result->fetch_array();
$quantity = intval($result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Please be aware of SQL Injection.
Also, I took a wild guess at the DB for in stock books, that will need to be changed.

```
require "conn.php";

$userID = "2";
$book_id = "1";

$mysql_qry = "SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books_checked_out WHERE bookID='" . $book_id . "') as num1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books_in_stock WHERE bookID='" . $book_id . "') as num2";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
$quantity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($quantity['num1'] >= 2) {
    echo "more books checked out than in stock";
}
else {
    echo "less books checked out than in stock";
}
//If you want to see the difference you can do something like this.

echo "Checked Out" . $quantity['num1'] . '<br/>';
echo "In Stock" . $quantity['num2'] . '<br/>';
```

Comment: I answered the question that was asked.  They didn't ask about sql injection.

Comment: Fixed the two queries and noted SQL Injection.  He is going to have to have two numbers if he is wanting the difference.  Number of books checked out and number of books in stock.  $book_id2 seem the best option since he referenced the first number as $book_id1.  Or, he can have the total number of books and deduct the total number checked out to get the remaining stock.

Answer (score 0):

try using 
`intval("0".$row['quantity'])`
This which will convert your quantity to integer.